# Rails - Inline scss file in Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, sass

I am on Rails 3.2 with assets pipeline.

I'd like to inline some minified css in a javascript string (to dynamically include it from a JS library I'm writing). My css is written using scss and my js using coffeescript.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Wait, why? Why not just include it in your haml/html/erb?

Comment: I don't have any html. I'm writing a JS library writing dynamic html/css in DOM

Comment: Ah interesting. Could you give me a more clearer example of what you're trying to do? I can probably help you

Comment: It's the following widget I am developing: http://www.sharypic.com/widget. As you can see, css is downloaded asynchronously and that makes web site to blink (content is first rendered unstyled and then css is downloaded). That's why I want to inline css in the widget js code.

Comment: Just distribute your library as a CSS file and a JavaScript file. This is how it's done literally everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @meagar to have a CSS and a JavaScript file.

However, if you really want to get it through javascript, you can add a async get call (like $.get) and handle the response as your new string. Ugly, hum?

Yet another option is to generate the CSS output and put it manually in your javascript, or better yet, loading it in your coffeescript file like this:

```
for filename in list
  do (filename) ->
    fs.readFile filename, (err, contents) ->
      compile filename, contents.toString()
```

(exemple from [coffescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/))